# error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-framework-version

I added a asp.net core 2 web api project (Empty) to an existing VS2017 solution which has already 7 projects with .NET Framework 4.6. I see an issue with the nuget package. I did a dotnet clean command from the Package Manager console pointing to the newly added asp.net core 2 project, I see the below mentioned error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

[image]

I did a Rebuild of the entire solution and see the below  error:

```
Error:Assets file 'C:\Temp\Test.CMS.API\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.  TaxatHand.CMS.API   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
```

Based on the above I did a dotnet restore in the Package Manager console pointing to the the newly added asp.net core 2 project

I see the following error with the above command:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Can anyone provide their guidance to fix this issue.